# cufon + accordion issue in IE 8.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, cufon

I am using jQuery UI Accordion on the website I am working on. The h2 tags are styled with Cufon, and everything works great in FF and Chrome. However, in IE 8.0 the h2 tags that I use for Accordion headers are not "clickable". Both area around them and arrow icons do expand/collapse the Accordion, but not the h2 titles themselves.

That is clearly a Cufon issue, because default font works just fine in IE 8.0. I can't really think of a solution for that, any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why you're using Cufon and not the @font-face? I'am just curious as, IMO, the licensing issues are similar with both solutions but Cufon is less flexible and slightly harder to implement?

Comment: I am using Latin and Cyrillic glyphs of a font for a multilingual website. The Cyrillic glyphs in a webfont generated by Font Squirrel looked awful in headings, no css shadow or webkit font smoothing helped a bit. It rendered particularly badly in Windows browsers and the audience of a website are 95% Windows users. I couldn't find a workaround for it -- although I read a lot of advice online. I had to use this particular font, so I couldn't find a better solution than Cufon. If you know any miracle font-smoothing techniques for @font-face, I would love to know them!

Answer (score 0):

Why to use Cufon in 2013. Web Fonts are [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface) by all browsers that are currently used, even IE6. Here is a great [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/) on that.

Comment: That is not the question I was asking. 

I have my reasons for using Cufon, due to website being promotional (meaning big headings) and therefore font anti-aliasing issues with the specific font that I had to use. I would have used Web Fonts otherwise.